# White screen when try to make a delete sql Query from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

My screen is white, no php errors, no sql errors... just white. What is wrong in my code?

```
<?PHP  require ("../SQL.php");
if($id=filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)); else
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$editare = "SELECT marca, model FROM modele WHERE id={$id};";
foreach ($dbh->query($editare) as $linie)
{
$id                    = $linie['id'];
$marca                 = $linie['marca'];
$model                 = $linie['model'];
} ?>
<?php require ("../SQL.php");   


$editare = "DELETE FROM modele WHERE id=$id"; 

if ($dbh->query($editare)) 
{
 print '<center><h2><img src="http://bahoy.tk/images/ok.png"></img><br /><br   />Telefonul/Tableta este sters!</h2><br />
Vei fi redirectionat in cateva momente inspre adaugarea unui nou model de tableta sau  telefon!
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=index.php"/></center>'; 
}
else(mysql_error())     
?>
```

I just want to delete all from specified `id` with one query.

Comment: set `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('log_errors', '1');`
and check in error log

Comment: What errors do you get and why do you include `SQL.php` twice?

Comment: Missing a `;` after the `mysql_error()`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski am I correct with pointing out the missing braces `{..}` on the following line: `else(mysql_error())`   -- should be: `else{ echo mysql_error(); }`

Comment: @DarylGill They're weird looking but actually will work.  Since it is only one statement, it doesn't need `{}` around it, and the `()` will just be treated as a statement grouping so that won't fail either. (of course, without an `echo`, that won't do anything useful)

Comment: It works now, I've putted `id` too befor `marca` on `SELECT` and it works!

Comment: Go check the server's error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ann error on line 4 :) 
Change this: `$editare = "SELECT id, marca, model FROM modele WHERE id={$id};";`

You forgot to read `id` too from table `modele`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that line. Columns in `WHERE` don't have to be in `SELECT`.

Comment: what is the error in this?

Comment: Thankyou Domuta, now it works, many many thanks! I've just put `id` too and it works!

Comment: the ID has not necessarily to be selected when working with it, in your Select part you only define the "Output" of the query, not the structure.